# Record and playback sound in OpenAL

Tags: c++, audio, record, playback, openal

I have one problem. I need to record and playback sound with OpenAL library. I founded this question: [OpenAL playback captured audio data c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886668/openal-playback-captured-audio-data-c), and I use first answer to solve my problem. But I dont understand, what I need write to file(audio data), without WAVEHEADER. Please help me.