# Circular buffers in OpenAL

Tags: streaming, openal, soundbuffer

In DirectSound, there was a very distinct concept of [circular buffers](http://books.google.ca/books?id=0TAE5me0GhwC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=directsound+circular+buffer&source=bl&ots=_6JyGW_VOW&sig=vrhu57_gGQIUlu9yQKAmUZRG8cU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z3DOUOqeEqigyAGYsoD4Cw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=directsound%20circular%20buffer&f=false)

In particular there was a current read position, a current write position, and clear methods to GetPosition and lock the buffer and start writing.

[image]

I'm looking for a similar concept in OpenAL, but all I can find is looping an `AL_STREAMING` buffer, and using `AL_SAMPLE_OFFSET` to determine the current read position (and write say, 15 samples after that?)

OpenAL docs are down right now, but accessible [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110513043311/http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf).

What is a safe way to declare a sound buffer that gets written to by the application *as it is playing*?  Am I right about using a looping streaming buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually circular buffers in OpenAL are much different than for DirectSound.

In OpenAL, you must **queue** sound buffers, one after the other.  You really only need 2 sound buffers then, and you just continuously call alSourceQueueBuffers and alSourceUnqueueBuffers.

> Queuing Buffers on a Source
>   To continuously stream audio from a source without interruption, buffer queuing is required. To
>   use buffer queuing, the buffers and sources are generated in the normal way, but alSourcei is not
>   used to attach the buffers to the source. Instead, the functions alSourceQueueBuffers and
>   alSourceUnqueueBuffers are used. The program can attach a buffer or a set of buffers to a
>   source using alSourceQueueBuffers, and then call alSourcePlay on that source. While the
>   source is playing, alSourceUnqueueBuffers can be called to remove buffers which have already
>   played. Those buffers can then be filled with new data or discarded. New or refilled buffers can
>   then be attached to the playing source using alSourceQueueBuffers. As long as there is always
>   a new buffer to play in the queue, the source will continue to play.

Comment: A while ago, I posted code demonstrating some simple code for microphone-to-speakers with optional filtering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087727/openal-how-to-create-simple-microphone-echo-programm This demonstrates the realtime editing that you're looking for.