# Syncing audio and video playback with OpenAL & C++

Tags: c++, openal

I am trying to create a webcam chat program in C++, and while I have been able to get the images to be captured sent and played, I am having trouble with doing the same with the audio: the audio lags and very quickly goes out of sync with the video, even when I just played it to myself.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5518320/2288890) answer and sample code to be really useful.

Are there any modifications I can make to this code to get it to be nearly lag free, or is OpenAL not right for this? I am using Windows, but I plan on making a linux version later.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are currently using please? (Or is it literally a verbatim copy of the code in the linked post?)

Comment: "lag" - Does the audio stutter, or is it just delayed?

Comment: With the settings from the link, it's delayed

Answer (score 0):

From the code linked:

```
ALCdevice* inputDevice = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL,FREQ,AL_FORMAT_MONO16,FREQ/2);
```

Try using a larger buffer:

```
ALCdevice* inputDevice = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL,FREQ,AL_FORMAT_MONO16,FREQ*4);
```

---

The polling is [very aggressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock). Try sleeping in the loop:

```
while (!done) {
    ...
}
```

To:

```
int sleepSeconds = 1;
while (!done) {
    ...
    Sleep(sleepSeconds/10) //windows, miliseconds
    //sleep(sleepSeconds) //linux, seconds
}
```