# Record Lowest quality possible with OpenAL?

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I'm currently using these settings with OpenAL and recording from a Mic:

```
BUFFERSIZE 4410 
FREQ 22050   // Sample rate
CAP_SIZE 10000 // How much to capture at a time (affects latency)
AL_FORMAT_MONO16
```

Is it possible to go lower in recording quality? I've tried reducing the sample rate but the end result is a faster playback speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so this is some of the most hacky code I've ever written, and I truly hope no one in their right mind ever uses it in production... just sooooo many bad things.

But to answer your question, I've been able to get the quality down to 8bitMono recording at 11025. However, everything I've recorded from my mic comes with significant amounts of static, and I'm not entirely sure I know why. I've generated 8bit karplus-strong string plucks that sound fantastic, so it could just be my recording device.

```
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

void sleep( clock_t wait )
{
   clock_t goal;
   goal = wait + clock();
   while( goal > clock() )
      ;
}

#define BUFFERSIZE  4410
const int SRATE = 11025;

int main()
{
    std::vector<ALchar> vBuffer;
    ALCdevice       *pDevice = NULL;
    ALCcontext      *pContext = NULL;
    ALCdevice       *pCaptureDevice;
    const ALCchar   *szDefaultCaptureDevice;
    ALint           iSamplesAvailable;
    ALchar          Buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    ALint           iDataSize = 0;
    ALint           iSize;

    // NOTE : This code does NOT setup the Wave Device's Audio Mixer to select a recording input
    // or a recording level.

    pDevice = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
    pContext = alcCreateContext(pDevice, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(pContext);

    printf("Capture Application\n");

    if (pDevice == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize OpenAL\n");
        //Shutdown code goes here
        return 0;
    }

    // Check for Capture Extension support
    pContext = alcGetCurrentContext();
    pDevice = alcGetContextsDevice(pContext);
    if (alcIsExtensionPresent(pDevice, "ALC_EXT_CAPTURE") == AL_FALSE){
        printf("Failed to detect Capture Extension\n");
        //Shutdown code goes here
        return 0;
    }

    // Get list of available Capture Devices
    const ALchar *pDeviceList = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_CAPTURE_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);
    if (pDeviceList){
        printf("\nAvailable Capture Devices are:-\n");

        while (*pDeviceList)
        {
            printf("%s\n", pDeviceList);
            pDeviceList += strlen(pDeviceList) + 1;
        }
    }

    // Get the name of the 'default' capture device
    szDefaultCaptureDevice = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_CAPTURE_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);
    printf("\nDefault Capture Device is '%s'\n\n", szDefaultCaptureDevice);

    pCaptureDevice = alcCaptureOpenDevice(szDefaultCaptureDevice, SRATE, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, BUFFERSIZE);
    if (pCaptureDevice)
    {
        printf("Opened '%s' Capture Device\n\n", alcGetString(pCaptureDevice, ALC_CAPTURE_DEVICE_SPECIFIER));

        // Start audio capture
        alcCaptureStart(pCaptureDevice);

        // Wait for any key to get pressed before exiting
        while (!_kbhit())
        {
            // Release some CPU time ...
            sleep(1);

            // Find out how many samples have been captured
            alcGetIntegerv(pCaptureDevice, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, 1, &iSamplesAvailable);

            printf("Samples available : %d\r", iSamplesAvailable);

            // When we have enough data to fill our BUFFERSIZE byte buffer, grab the samples
            if (iSamplesAvailable > (BUFFERSIZE / 2))
            {
                // Consume Samples
                alcCaptureSamples(pCaptureDevice, Buffer, BUFFERSIZE / 2);

                // Write the audio data to a file
                //fwrite(Buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 1, pFile);
                for(int i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE / 2; i++){
                    vBuffer.push_back(Buffer[i]);
                }

                // Record total amount of data recorded
                iDataSize += BUFFERSIZE / 2;
            }
        }

        // Stop capture
        alcCaptureStop(pCaptureDevice);

        // Check if any Samples haven't been consumed yet
        alcGetIntegerv(pCaptureDevice, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, 1, &iSamplesAvailable);
        while (iSamplesAvailable)
        {
            if (iSamplesAvailable > (BUFFERSIZE / 2))
            {
                alcCaptureSamples(pCaptureDevice, Buffer, BUFFERSIZE / 2);
                for(int i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE/2; i++){
                    vBuffer.push_back(Buffer[i]);
                }
                iSamplesAvailable -= (BUFFERSIZE / 2);
                iDataSize += BUFFERSIZE;
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO::Fix
                alcCaptureSamples(pCaptureDevice, Buffer, iSamplesAvailable);
                for(int i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE/2; i++){
                    vBuffer.push_back(Buffer[i]);
                }
                iDataSize += iSamplesAvailable * 2;
                iSamplesAvailable = 0;
            }
        }

        alcCaptureCloseDevice(pCaptureDevice);
    }

    //TODO::Make less hacky
    ALuint bufferID;                        // The OpenAL sound buffer ID
    ALuint sourceID;                        // The OpenAL sound source

    // Create sound buffer and source
    alGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
    alGenSources(1, &sourceID);

    alListener3f(AL_POSITION, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    alSource3f(sourceID, AL_POSITION, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    alBufferData(bufferID, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, &vBuffer[0], static_cast<ALsizei>(vBuffer.size()), SRATE);

    // Attach sound buffer to source
    alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, bufferID);

    // Finally, play the sound!!!
    alSourcePlay(sourceID);

    printf("Press any key to continue...");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see from:

```
alBufferData(bufferID, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, &vBuffer[0], static_cast<ALsizei>(vBuffer.size()), SRATE);
```

I've verified that this is the case. For demonstration code I'm okay throwing this example out there, but I wouldn't ever use it in production.

Comment: Yeah I get static/snow as well. That's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but for me FREQ is the output frequency but not the sample rate.
define sampling-rate 48000
see this link : http://supertux.lethargik.org/wiki/OpenAL_Configuration

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087727/openal-how-to-create-simple-microphone-echo-programm

I modified this snippet.

Comment: Also setting the sampling rate 11020 makes the audio sound like Mickey Mouse. Setting it to 48000 makes it sounds slow.

Comment: If you're playing from a file/buffer, you still have the same amount of raw data that it's trying to play through, so this behavior is to be expected. When you say "lower quality" you could convert your file/buffer to 8bit mono, or to 8khz, and then try playing it.

Comment: I've updated the question to mention that I'm recording from a Mic and saving the file to a .wav. No playback this time.